# Omit field in tuple

Tags: typescript

```
type Tu=[{a:'a1',b:'b1'},{a:'a2',b:'b2'}]
type R=TupleOmit<Tu,'b'> // = [{a:'a1'},{a:'a2'}]

type ERR =Omit<Tu[number],'b'>// = {a:'a1'|'a2'} This is wrong type
```

I want a generic type to omit one filed on tuple's each item. How to implement generic type `TupleOmit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to apply omit to each member of the tuple:

```
type Tu=[{a:'a1',b:'b1'},{a:'a2',b:'b2'}]
type TupleOmit<T extends any[], K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Omit<T[P], K>
}
type R=TupleOmit<Tu,'b'> // = [{a:'a1'},{a:'a2'}]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgVwLwG0DeBDAXAcgwRhwBoAjXEwgXyM1wwCZiycTHKBdUSWRCAGygB5ALYBLEAB44MKAA8QUAHYATAM4wMisCnZEYAaRnylamAAUATgHtoF8PqhgAfDCQw0wGF5gozMUYowANaOVgBm8OxYMCLiUr66Bk7AlFzQMABKSLwCsZKIRCw4LgD0Ja4+tHhUNNh4bJzAQA)

Comment: `keyof T` includes array's prototype methods like `splice`. How do this type deal with them?

Comment: And `keyof Tu` is `number | "0" | "1" | "length" ....`, how can I filter the keys to index `"0" | "1"...`?

Comment: @leili tuples and array types are special cased in mapped types, they don't map the intrinsic properties of the tuple/array https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063